# How we concatenation of key value of object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want if the hash to be the same then all objects key attribute 'values' got merged. and I don't want to use the spread operator in my code.
Here is my input:

```
[
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": []
  },
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": [4]
  },
  {
    "hash": "6789",
    "values": [9]
  },
  {
    "hash": "6789",
    "values": [1]
  }
]
```

Here is the output I want

```
[
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": [1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": [1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "hash": "12345",
    "values": [1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "hash": "6789",
    "values": [1,9]
  },
  {
    "hash": "6789",
    "values": [1,9]
  }
]
```

Comment: You will need to iterate over the structure of array of objects and implement the logic you want. As always, please post the code you're having trouble with if you've hit a roadblock and need debugging help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this maybe

```js
const map = arr.reduce(
    (acc, x) =>
        acc.has(x.hash)
            ? acc.set(x.hash, acc.get(x.hash).concat(x.values))
            : acc.set(x.hash, x.values),
    new Map()
)
arr.forEach(x => x.values = map.get(x.hash).sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

You can do that with an object as well:

```js
const map = arr.reduce(
    (acc, x) =>
        acc[x.hash]
            ? (acc[x.hash] = acc[x.hash].concat(x.values), acc)
            : ((acc[x.hash] = x.values), acc),
    {}
)
arr.forEach(x => x.values = map[x.hash].sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

Comment: I don't want to use the spread operator here. can suggest something else?

Comment: @AqeelKhadim I missed the part with hash, now it's fixed

Comment: Can you explain what the reduce part does?

Comment: @AqeelKhadim it creates a map that has hashes as keys and concatenated values of objects with that hash as values.